# Java - Compare the performance of linear search and binary search

Tags: java, arrays, binary-search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between Linear search and Binary search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700241/what-is-the-difference-between-linear-search-and-binary-search)

> Write a program that  generates 20 random integers within the range
>   from 0 to 100.  Sort the array in descending order. Then, accepts an
>   integer input from the user. Then,  search the array using this
>   number. Compare the performance of linear search and  binary search.

Here is my code

```
import java.util.Arrays;    
import java.util.Scanner;

public class search {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] num = new int[20];
        for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {

            num[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 101);
        }
        System.out.println("A list of 20 random intergers with 0 - 100");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(num));
        for (int j = 1; j < num.length; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < num.length - 1; k++) {
                if (num[k] < num[k + 1]) {
                    int hold = num[k + 1];
                    num[k + 1] = num[k];
                    num[k] = hold;
                }
            }

        }
        System.out.println("Array in descending order");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(num));
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number to search: ");
        int num2 = input.nextInt();
        int loop = 0;
        for ( int cnt = 0; cnt < num.length; cnt++ )
        {
            if ( num[cnt] == num2 )
            {
                loop = cnt;
                System.out.println(num2+ " found"); 
          }

        }
        System.out.println("Linear search - "+loop+ " loop(s)");
        int loop2 = 0;
        int low = 0;   // low element subscript
        int high = num.length - 1;  // high element subscript
        int middle;    // middle element subscript
        while ( low <= high ) {
            middle = ( low + high ) / 2;
            if ( num2 == num[ middle ] ) { 

            }
            else if ( num2 > num[ middle ] )
            {
              low = middle +1;
               loop2++;
            }
            else{
              high = middle - 1;   
               loop2++;
            }                      
      }
        System.out.println("Binary search - "+loop2+ " loop(s)");
    }
}
```

I can get number of loop of Linear search. However, I can't get binary search loops number.

Comment: What do you mean you "can't get it"? Do you have an error or something?

Comment: `Compare the performance of linear search and binary search` might also mean the number of comparisons performed rather than counting the number of loops.

Comment: what is the output of `System.out.println("Binary search - "+loop2+ " loop(s)");`?

Comment: Might I suggest that you `break` out of your search if you find the element you're looking for. If you don't, you will always get worst case for both searches.

Answer (score 3):

Your binary search is missing a break in:

```
        if ( num2 == num[ middle ] ) { 

        }
```

Also your binary search is for ascending order but you actually have a descending order! Either reverse your sort or adjust your search algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use the comparison-count in place of loop-count as it reflects more the cost of the algorithms. You can easily count the comparisons. In this particular case though, the two happen to be equivalent.

```
int comparisons = 0;
while ( low <= high ) {
   middle = ( low + high ) / 2;
   ++comparisons;
   if ( num2 > num[ middle ] ) {
      low = middle +1;
   }
   else if ( num2 < num[ middle ] ) {
      high = middle - 1;   
   }
   else {
      break;
   }               
}
System.out.println( "Binary search - " + comprisons + " loop(s)");
```

Comment: Downvoting. If you want to count comparisons, you should count both branches of the if statement. Counting one half isn't enough. Even the case for equality is also a comparison. So, loop counting is the right thing to do.

Comment: You're right, sorry. I have edited the source.

Comment: I removed the downvote. You can still reduce the number of comparisons made by your code though, if you combine all three comparisons into one if-else-if-else structure. Right now you're always doing the equality check in every iteration. I've edited your code reflect this, if it's not ok with you, feel free to revert.