# Improve performance on Python nested for loop

Tags: python, performance, loops

I have two sets of numbers, each in a list in my Python script. For each number in the first list, I need to see if any of the numbers in the second are larger than it. I only need the number of times that an n2 was larger than an n1. (For example, if `numset1` is `[7,2]` and `numset2` is `[6,9]`, I just need 3)
Right now I'm doing this - going through each n1 and checking if each n2 is larger than it:

```
possibilities = [(n1<n2) for n1 in numset1 for n2 in numset2]
numPossibilities = sum(possibilities)
```

Currently this is the slowest portion of my script, particularly when dealing with larger datasets (numset1 and numset2 containing thousands of numbers). I'm sure there's some way to make this more efficient, I'm just not sure how.

Comment: What about sorting one list and using the `bisect` module ?

Comment: Err, I swear I didn't see your comment before I posted my answer! If you want to post yours I'll delete mine :)

Comment: I didn't see your answer either :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort `numset2` and then iterate over `numset1` but use a binary search on `numset2`, for example using the bisect module: http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html

```
import bisect
# your code here
numset2.sort()
L = len(numset2)
numPossibilities = sum([bisect.bisect_right(numset2,n1) < L for n1 in numset1])
```

Also note that your original code does not compute what you have asked for in your second sentence - for each element in `numset1`, it sums *how many elements* in `numset2` are greater than this element, not *whether* there is an element that matches the criterion.

To match your original code, do:

```
numPossibilities = sum([L - bisect.bisect_right(numset2,n1) for n1 in numset1])
```

Comment: I don't believe you can sort a `set`.

Comment: I think the chosen variable names are misleading - the questions states "I have two sets of numbers, each in a list in my Python script." ...

Comment: I don't think this code snippet actually works correctly.  At the very least, the `< L` part is suspicious - you probably want to sum the number of entries to the left of the bisection point - i.e. the actual return value of bisect_right

Comment: @happydave , yes, I have added a note about this. It depends on whether you want the code that matches the result in the question, or the description in the question.

Comment: @MrE Sorry, I should've worded that differently. The code listed in my question does what I want, so go with what the code does, not what my bad description says.

Comment: That works great, it's >100x as fast! Also, I'm new to this type of stuff, would you happen to know of some resource that would explain/introduce this type of stuff? The Python doc link was great, but I'm still a bit lost as to how it works.

Comment: That's great - what in particular do you need explaining? [This link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Overview) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/700241/what-is-the-difference-between-linear-search-and-binary-search) should help with understanding why things are faster, and why I sorted the list.

Comment: In particular, `bisect_right` [uses a binary search](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/bisect.py) to find the index of the first element greater than `n1`, (returning `len(numset2)` if all the elements are `<= n1`), so the expression `L - bisect_right(numset2,n1)` gives us the number of elements in `numset2` that are greater than `n1`. Here `L` is `len(numset2)`.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you have to iterate over each combination of `(n1, n2)`, and there are `len(numset1) * len(numset2)` combinations, which gets really large when `numset1` and `numset2` are only fairly large.

Put a different way, the running time of your algorithm is O(n^2) (if `len(numset1)` is about equal to `len(numset2)`.  Let's make that runtime faster. :-)

This becomes a lot easier to do if we sort the lists.  So let's sort `numset1` and `numset2`.

```
>>> numset1.sort()
>>> numset2.sort()
```

Now, compare the smallest element of `numset1` (call it `n1`) and the smallest element of `numset2` (call it `n2`).  If `n1` is smaller, then we know that there are `len(numset2)` elements in `numset2` larger than it.  If `n2` is smaller, we know that no elements in `numset1` are smaller than it.

Now, we don't want to actually delete elements from the beginning of the list, because that's an O(n) operation on a Python list.  So instead, let's keep track of where we are in each list and iterate through.

```
>>> n1_idx, n2_idx, accumulator = 0, 0, 0
>>> while n1_idx < len(numset1) and n2_idx < len(numset2):
        if numset1[n1_idx] < numset2[n2_idx]:
            accumulator += len(numset2) - n2_idx
            n1_idx += 1
        else:
            n2_idx += 1
```

At the end of this operation, we've spent O(nlog(n)) time sorting the lists and O(n) time doing our iteration, so our overall runtime complexity is O(nlog(n)).

That, and `accumulator` has the number of `(n1, n2)` pairs where `n1 < n2`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what should be a pretty efficient implementation:

```
def get_possibilities(numset1, numset2):
    sortset1 = sorted(numset1)
    sortset2 = sorted(numset2)
    total = 0
    i2 = 0
    for i1, n1 in enumerate(sortset1, 1):
        while sortset2[i2] <= n1:
            i2 += 1
            if i2 >= len(sortset2):
                # reached end of i2, so just return total now
                return total
            # current from sortset2 is greater than from sortset1 so far
            total += i1
    # all remaining elements of sortset2 greater than all elements of sortset1
    total += (len(sortset2) - i2 - 1) * len(sortset1)
    return total
```

This iterates over each set only once, which it accomplishes by sorting the sets before running.  This allows some improved logic, because if the element in `sortset2` at index `i2` is greater than an element of `sortset1` at index `i1`, then it is also greater than all elements in `sortset1` at earlier indices.